# PgAdmin4 unable to query or view data

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I have a very basic PostgreSql table. Despite the simple table schema, I cannot query it via PgAdmin4.

The `View Data` option is unresponsive; `Query Tool` option becomes unresponsive after a few attempts in opening and closing the panel. When the Query Tool is eventually (somehow) launched, a trivial SQL statement like

> `SELECT * FROM test_table`

will spin forever and never display.

[image: View of Database]

The diagram above shows the exact same table, which is okay under PgAdmin3.

The table was created empty. Then added with a row. But it threw errors about not having a Primary Key. Which also threw errors when I tried to set a Primary Key. So I used TeamPostgreSql to set a Primary Key. So all is good under PgAdmin3 now. Hence I'm really curious about what's going on with PgAdmin4?

Comment: It's not "Postgres" that's problematic - it's pgAdmin

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, and by the way pgAdmin4 is hardly 6 months old open source project and may contains bugs but you can logged the bugs and help developers to improve the product. https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgadmin4

Comment: I see... I wasn't aware of that. But in terms of bug severity, not being able to query or view data is pretty high on the catastrophic level. If I find some time a few weeks down I might log a bug, but for now I'm downgrading to PgAdmin3

Comment: I also have had many problems in windows when trying the different version of pgadmin4. Pgamin III is taking 3 s to open, while pgadmin IV1.6 is much slower 20s. And I'm not able to run any query and don't get anything in the log indicated by n33ma below; Access to the database is also very slow and I'm unable to run any queries. I understand while googling that this is a windows related problem, I hope the developers find a way arround this problem.

Comment: Apparently this bug is still present atm

Comment: I installed pgadmin4 in Windows 10 and the Query Tool doesn't work at all, it just says "Initializing query execution..." forever. I can do anything else, but the query tool just doesn't work. I google and found heaps of similar reports with no solution, just requests for debug logs.

Comment: Use any other database management tool, e.g: DbVisualiser, which comes with default PostgreSQL support or anything else on the free web but not pgadmin. WIth pgadmin I had the worst db management experience so far. Don't go for it. Please.

Answer (score 64):

I'm running pgAdmin4 v3.0 and I've put `localhost` as host name.

I mean, `left panel > servers > create > server` and then `connection tab > host name`

I could not query tables, clicking on `view/edit data` > `all rows` had no results (nor error log entries).

After I changed server name from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, **all worked as expected!**

I hope it helps, because I've lost so much time on this and could not find a proper answer.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Seems like a pgAdmin bag.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me as well. I was about to install pgAdmin III cause the query tool was not showing and I couldn't view tables as well. This should be mentioned somewhere in the docs to save people some frustration!

Comment: This worked for me in pgAdmin 4 v 3.1. I had problem with a tcp tunneling to the server via websocket. but query initialization tool started to work after changing to 127.0.0.1 in place for localhost. the local server still works without it.

Comment: Worked for me in pgAdmin 4 v3.3. I was connecting to a remote postgresql instance on google cloud.

Comment: Worked for me in pgAdmin 4 3.4.  I was connecting to a Postgres Docker image running on my developer Windows machine.

Comment: still happening in the latest pgadmin 4.11

Comment: Just tripped me up in July, 2021.  needed to set my search_path too.

Comment: This problem still exists in pgAdmin4 v6.4, at least for Windows connecting to postgresql running in WSL.

Comment: Still a bug in pgAdmin 4 v6.8

Answer (score 61):

I find a way to view query result on Data Output window using the "Reset Layout" command from File menu. Save your current work (query) before as it will kind of restart pgAdmin4. Tested with pgAdmin 2.1

[image: File -> Reset Layout]

Comment: Working perfect for me!!

Comment: Yes it works thanks. I Was swelling up with foul air

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem.

For me the **Query Tool** did render, however I could not see the Query Tool until **after** I expanded the view.

Then even after expanding I was not able to see the result of the query until I ran **(** `File -> Reset Layout` **)** as [Guillaume Raymond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1379243/guillaume-raymond) suggest.

[Before Expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsNZI.png)

[After Expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9LBQ.png)

[After Running Reset Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap9Ao.png)

Answer (score 4):

1) First delete the log file to get rid of older logs

2) Start pgAdmin4.

3) Try to view data again

Can you check log file for any errors & paste it here?

> Linux log location: ~/.pgadmin/pgadmin4.log
>
> Windows log location:
>   C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.log

Comment: No errors at all. The "Database Activity" panel showed that I was querying the table, but the State: "Idle". I see the Transactions happening, but literally nothing else happens.

Comment: I am not getting error you mentioned, I have version 1.2 installed.
Did you try with current version pgAdmin4 (version 1.2) ?

Download: https://www.pgadmin.org/

Answer (score 4):

Try naming your columns with lower case letters.

Or try with a blank query and write the SQL commands manually:

```
SELECT * FROM “test_table”
ORDER BY “Apple” ASC
```

I think this is a bug. The command the pgAdmin 4 is sending, does not contain the double quotes in the order command on the column name, and if you have upper case letters, SQL is going to convert them to lower case letters, thus not finding the sorting criteria.

Answer (score 2):

**I fixed this by opening the connection, changing just the connection name and saving the connection.**

Based on other comments, I'd say there is likely some difference in the persisted format of the connection and they need to be resaved by the new version to work.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: You may need to recreate connections.

This worked for me.

1.) Shutdown pgadmin4 3.1

2.) Delete folder:   C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar issue where the problem was caused by Firefox, pgADmin 4. Launching pgAdmin in Chrome solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem I experienced with the internet explorer browser where the query tool was not loading at all. It just kept on spinning with a circle. I solved this issue by using chrome browser.

When you launch pgadmin4 it launches in internet explorer by deafult. it has a key attached to it like

http://127.0.0.1:57756/?key=0371aabd-b4c7-4454-8234-b1234416d7e5e.

you can just paste the above url in the browser directly and the pgadmin4 will open 
and query tool works in it. Or you cna use cmd and paste the belwo command and pgadmin4 will open as a standlone application rather tahn another tab in the browser and you cna use it like old pgadmin3.

C:\windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://127.0.0.1:57756/?key=0371aabd-b4c7-4454-8234-b1234416d7e5e

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (version 4.18). Only the following worked for me:

1. Create a new server group (!) by right-clicking on "servers" in the left-hand navigation.
2. In this new group I created the desired connection to the database (with host name 127.0.0.1)

After that I could finally work with it

Answer (score 0):

You can remove pgadmin4, then reinstall it. It worked for me. I used Ubuntu 18.04.
Here is my command on terminal:

1. sudo apt autoremove pgadmin4
2. sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2 -y

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had a dumb issue. I had my DATABASE_URL pointing to another server

DATABASE_URL='postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/wrong-database'.

Even though my DATABASE_NAME='correct-database'.

And in my settings.py I was running

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env).

Please make sure your .env file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem by combining two of the above solutions it worked for me:

1. I changed Hostname from localhost to IP address 127.0.0.1
2. Click file on menu bar >> click reset layout