# PGadmin cant connect when see data rows

Tags: postgresql, heroku-postgres, pgadmin-4

I'm using Pgadmin 4 with heroku & prisma project,
When I start using Pgadmin, I can connect with my database. but when I go to my table and see my data,  I'm always got red plugin icon. What should I do to solve this?

[image]

I'm already google for it, but not get the solution, please help. Thanks

Comment: Could you try with latest nightly build from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/snapshots/2019-01-13/

Comment: @n33rma im already try that version, but i still get the same issue

Comment: disconnect your server, then connect again. Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466916/pgadmin4-unable-to-query-or-view-data

Answer (score 0):

I have also gone through the same issue when connected to Heroku postgres, could not find the correct solution.
Then I installed pgAdmin III and connected, it worked perfectly alright. Now I can see table rows.